# What is $\nu$ in $\nu$-SVM controlling?

Tags: svm

I have read the $\nu$-SVM formulation, but still cannot understand the intuition behind introducing $\nu$. Can anyone give a interpretation of the parameter?

I read about it from this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.94.2928&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This in turn was referred in the book Learning with Kernels.

Comment: A citation for whatever it is you read might help contextualize your problem

Comment: good idea. let me add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really nice geometric interpretation is given in this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.5498), which in addition provides a bound on the value of $\nu$ for which there is a non-trivial solution.

The basic idea is that solving the optimization problem amounts to finding the shortest vector that connects the convex hulls containing the data points of different classes. This idea is extended to overlapping convex hulls.

Answer (score 2):

$\nu$ is a parameter in $(0,1]$ which allows you to control the model complexity. It is an upper bound on the fraction of training errors and a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors of the resulting model.

For example, if you set $\nu=1\%$, you will have at most $1\%$ training misclassifications and at least $1\%$ of the training set will become support vectors.

You can find more information [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) (section 2.2, pages 4-5).